# How to respond to a co-worker that minimizes my position or makes jokes? Sometimes in front of others

Tags: communication

I have been working detail assignment for the last 18 months that required a certain skill set and certifications.  Not many people put it for the assignment at the time because many did not understand the requirements of the position since it was a new position or did not possess he necessary skill set to apply.  In the beginning, I had some insecurities about being successful.  I slowly got past them as time went on.

Nonetheless, now that I have established myself in the position, I have been getting snarking "jokes"/comments by co-workers minimizing the value of the position and how "I got it made" etc.

I have played it cool, but wish I had a witty professional comeback so they would think twice of doing it again and respect the position.  I hate to admit it but it but those unsecure feelings are lingering in mind again.  Please advise.

Comment: Stay away from him/her and talk only when needed.

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: I've had jobs like that. They would call my area the 'country club' and whatever. Don't worry about it. They are just jealous. As long as you do good work and your paycheck clears, what does it really matter?

Comment: Call the college to the coffee and explain that you do not like his/her attitude. To avoid further conflicts recommend him/her not to discuss anything related to your job in front of you... I mean he/she is not the one paying you the salary why the hell he/she judges your work and achievements... It is your right to defend yourself and your working environment. Might sound aggressive, but he is being rude to you... Many might disagree, but it worked for me in the past and will work for sure in future.

Comment: "Yes I do have it made.  Too bad you did not qualify for the position."

Comment: I have no idea how other people deal with this, but my personal tactic is to play the victims "pff, if you think it that way...", "do you believe you are funny ?", although it's far from always adapted or easy. Your goal with them is to be able to prove them they went too far when they do, and set some limits.

Comment: I'm with Frisbee on this.  When they make a comment like that, just respond with an enthusiastic "Yeah, it's great isn't it?" and smile.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to ignore such people, it's unlikely anything you do or say will change them, at best you will antagonise them. Most probably they are just joking around, and if they're part serious it is because they are envious or trying to show off.

The closest I have come to this situation is telling a guy that I could learn his job in 5 minutes and do it better than him. But he could try for ten years and not do mine as well. Not terribly witty, but it shut him up.

Comment: While I agree that ignoring them is likely the best solution, I think that saying something like "you can learn his job in 5 minutes.. etc" is very antagonistic and would almost certainly lead to bad blood

Comment: Ignoring this person is often the worst action you can take if he has any organizational influence. You can get your reputation ruined and not be able to recover. I find it i best to address such things immediately and never accept being put down in an office situation. Turning the joke around on them is usually the more effective route.

Comment: @Kialandei: So what's wrong wit "bad blood"? If someone makes it their goal in life to upset and annoy you, then a bit of bad blood doesn't make it worse. Especially if something like what Kilisi said is true.

Comment: @gnasher729 It's never going to be constructive to intentionally create hostility/arguments in the work place. Two wrongs don't make a right. Stooping to someone else's level is just going to get you bogged down in some kind of feud until one or the other of you oversteps the boundaries and gets themselves fired. That's perhaps an extreme case, but at the least it's going to be one of those things that stops you wanting to get up and go to work and deal with day in and day out.

Comment: @Kialandei the hostility has already been created, best to nip it in the bud precisely so it stops affecting you day in day out.

Comment: @Kilisi But responding in this fashion won't nip it in the bud. Nipping it in the bud would be opening up a discussion on the problem saying "Look, I know we've had our differences and I've said things I wish I hadn't but can we put this behind us and try and be amicable from now on". Responding with more insults/jabs isn't going to stop the responses so much as make more of them.

Comment: @Kialandei actually since it's a real life scenario, I know the outcome better than you, and it nipped it in the bud. Many people can hand out aggravation but are not so keen on getting it back.